# socket-io emits from server not received by native non-browser clients but recieved by browser clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is the description of what I have written.

ioServer1.js file creates a socket.io server and opens a port to listen at 3000. The same file also opens a client connection to the server with port 3001 (using socket.io-client). ioSever1.js also serves index.html when accessed via the browser (using localhost:3000). index.html is written which behaves as the browser client to the server. ioServer1.js uses io.emit to emit to all clients on a new connection.

ioServer2.js is the same as ioServer1.js except that it listens on 3001 and opens a client connection to 3000.

I run ioServer1.js and ioServer2.js on two different git bash terminals. Here is what happens:

All the client ---> server messages are correctly received and logged; whether the client is terminal native based or browser based.

On server ---> client messages. The io.emit and socket.emit from the server to clients are being received by any browser client but *not* by the native client. Thus the terminal running ioServer1.js (which is a client to ioServer2) does not log any messages from server ioServer2.js.

I am including the code in ioServer1.js and index.html files. The ioServer2.js file is only different in the port it is listening to (3001) and makes a client connection to (3000). Any help with debugging is appreciated

**ioServer1.js:**

```
var port="3000";
var express=require('express');
app=express();
var http=require('http');
var server=http.createServer(app).listen(port);
var io=require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(express.static('./'));

console.log(`io server listening on port ${port}`);

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log(`Connection by socket with id ${socket.id}`);//This works

        socket.emit("message",`socket.emitMsgFromServer3000: You are being Served by port: ${port}`);//Works only for browser clients
        io.emit("message",`io.emitMsgOriginSever3000:socket with id ${socket.id} connected`);//Works only for browser clients


    socket.on("initialMessageFromClient",(message)=>{
            console.log(message);
        });
    socket.on("message",(message)=>{
            console.log(message);
        });

});

var socketioClient = require('socket.io-client');// Making a client connection to 3001
ip='http://localhost:3001';
neighborRpi2=socketioClient.connect(ip, {reconnection: true});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="socket.io-client.min.js"></script> ><!-- this is needed for client to communicate back to server -->
    <script>
    var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});  /*socket.io-client.min.js needed for this */
    socket.on('connect',()=>{
        /* Emit a message to server with IRQ "initialMessageFromClient" */
        socket.emit("initialMessageFromClient","MsgFromClient: Hello");
    });
    socket.on("message",(message)=>{
        printMessage(message);
    });

    function printMessage(message) {
        $("#messages").append($('<li>').text(message)); /* Jquery is being used here to get to id messages in index.html */
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
This is the Client
<!-- Thus div has id messages. Client code in client.js populates this div -->
    <div id="messages"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you also add the code where you listen for `message` to `neighborRpi2` ?

Comment: The ioServer1.js (edited) has the code for what happens when "message" is triggered on socket.on. Thanks for pointing that this was missing in my question here; it is there in my implementation (i.e. the problem persists)

Comment: You're choosing to exclude the code where your program is failing. Could you please add that.

Comment: I am not quite following. When the socket.io-client based connection from ioServer2.js is made to port 3000; the ioServer1.js is supposed to emit a message "io.emitMsgOriginSever3000:socket with id ${socket.id} connected". This should be received by all clients. socket.on("message",...) should console log the message. Am I going wrong somewhere. I am not excluding any code.

Comment: Yes, where do you receive that message ?

Comment: You need something like `neighborRpi2.on('message',...)`

Comment: Here is one  sequence of events I am envisioning (i) ioServer2.js initiates a connection to  port 3000 (2) io.on in the ioServer1.js receives the connection and receives the socket (3) ioServer1.js uses socket.emit and io.emit to emit messages on a new connection. (4) The socket.on("message",...) on ioServer2.js should log the message.

Comment: No. I've added some code as answer. That might help you clear it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for messages on the CLI client

```
var port = "3000";
var express = require('express');
app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(express.static('./'));

console.log(`io server listening on port ${port}`);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`Connection by socket with id ${socket.id}`); //This works

    socket.emit("message", `socket.emitMsgFromServer3000: You are being Served by port: ${port}`); //Works only for browser clients
    io.emit("message", `io.emitMsgOriginSever3000:socket with id ${socket.id} connected`); //Works only for browser clients

    socket.on("initialMessageFromClient", (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });    
});

var socketioClient = require('socket.io-client'); // Making a client connection to 3001
ip = 'http://localhost:3001';
neighborRpi2 = socketioClient.connect(ip, {
    reconnection: true
});
neighborRpi2.on('connect', () => {
    neighborRpi2.emit("initialMessageFromClient", "MsgFromClient: Hello");
});
neighborRpi2.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("Recieved on CLI client", message);
});
```